# How to subtract two date using PHP not difference

Tags: php, date

I am a newbie programmer, I would like to know how I can subtract two dates

My sample is

```
$datetoday = date("Y/m/d");
$dateprev = "2015/11/03";
```

All I want is, if `$datetoday` is greater than `$dateprev`, that the output is a positive value.

If `$dateprev` is greater than `$datetoday`, the output should be a negative value.

Comment: [Check This](https://3v4l.org/IKitE)

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtotime function on those dates to turn them into integers (unix/epoch timestamp) and compare them that way.

And the time() function will get the current date/time directly as the unix timestamp.

Comment: sir i dont use time.. :(... in my sample the output will be positive 10

Comment: You can still use strtotime to convert it to an integer. If you don't have an explicit time defined then it will just compare midnight.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these code for date difference :-

```
<?php
     $val1 = '2014-03-18 10:34:09.939';
     $val2 = '2014-03-18 10:34:09.940';

     $datetime1 = new DateTime($val1);
     $datetime2 = new DateTime($val2);

    if($datetime1 > $datetime2)
        echo "1 is bigger";
    else
        echo "2 is bigger";
?>
```

Comment: goo day sir.. i use that code also.. but the output alway.. positive... because i erase their the %R..

Comment: in my sample code sir.. the output will be 10..  if vise versa.. it will be -10

Comment: sir...  if i delete the time.. it is ok?

Answer (score 0):

You could use diff from the DateTime Interface. Here is a code example:

```
$datetoday = new DateTime();
$dateprev = new DateTime('2015/11/03');
$interval = $dateprev->diff($datetoday);
echo $interval->format('%R%a');
```